# Creating an unique export data VBA Macro Function in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

new to this site as well as new to Excel VBA in general. I've been given an existing spreadsheet with quite a bit of information to process and was wondering is someone here might be able to provide insight in creating a VBA function to do the heavy lifting.

My challenge is that there is alot of data that needs to remain in the original format but for our analytics it is functional to have the data exported to a format shown in the second picture below.

Is there a function that will cycle through the X headers and then return the value associated with the corresponding Y header and work it's way through the different combinations?

Original data format:

[image]

Desired Export data format:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Slf7SI7.jpg]

Any help on this would be much appreciated! The origin data is constantly evolving so it will turn into a never-ending copy paste exercise for me if I can't find a solution.

Thanks,

Jason

Update:Thanks for the tips guys. I looked into an unpivot code and was able to find this as a resource and it works!:

```
  Sub NormalizeData()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WS As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set Rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select a range to normalize data" _
, Title:="Select a range", Default:=ActiveCell.Address, Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

If Rng Is Nothing Then
Else
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set WS = Sheet1
i = 0
For c = 1 To Rng.Columns.Count - 1
For r = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count - 1
        WS.Range("A2").Offset(i, 0) = Rng.Offset(0, c).Value
        WS.Range("A2").Offset(i, 1) = Rng.Offset(r, 0).Value
        WS.Range("A2").Offset(i, 2) = Rng.Offset(r, c).Value
        i = i + 1
    Next r
Next c
WS.Range("A:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
End Sub
```

An image of the results is as follows:

[image: http://imgur.com/3KRikBK]

I'm still tweaking it to make it user friendly. Any further tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you always going to have a 3x3 table for heading 1 and heading 2?

Comment: Where are the "Headings" in the output sheet coming from? Also, this is the sort of thing that pivot tables excel at. (No pun intended.)

Comment: Unfortunately the tables will vary in size. My mistake, there is no need for headings in the output sheet. I was just trying to delineate that i would prefer the data in different columns.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve could be called "unpivot". Please try to google it and you will find samples with multiple consolidation ranges pivot table and vba.